# How to hide the source of a download on a webpage

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to hide the source of my download. I'm surprised this is not more covered, but it also makes me wonder whether it's possible.

(**Edit:** By hide I mean make it difficult or impossible for end user to find a direct link to the file. They will thus be forced to actually be on the page, clicking it, for it to work.)

I found a script to force download files that are locally stored. The way I see it, it hides the true source (at least it's not in view source or download history).

http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/12/how-to-force-file-download-with-php/

So this works, I made it into a function that gets a linkID, and check that with a DB for the actual file-source. Hooray!

Only what if your downloads are on another server? Then you can't use most of the functions used here (like filesize, isreadable, fopen, ...). I'm not proficient enough to decide whether it is possible/feasible to make this work cross-server.

I realize that probably my webserver will lose bandwidth even though files aren't stored there, that's not a big issue.

Any info on the subject would be greatly appreciated. I prefer PHP, but I can work with whatever you give me, I really have no idea about this one.

Comment: I don't really understand "hide the source".

Comment: My understanding from reading this is that he wants to link users to remote downloads, but conceal the remote location while not providing a link that would work for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry not possible. You HAVE to tell the browser where the resource is located so any savy user can simply decode the address or scan the HTTP request or their firewall logs or download history in the browser.

If you're trying to hide the path on your server then URL rewriting with mod_rewrite or aliases or other similar method should be sufficient.

UPDATE: Ok if using your own bandwidth is not an issue then all you need to be doing is outputting the files binary content to the browser and setting the relevant HTTP headers (ie, Content-Type and Content-Disposition). If the files MUST be stored remotely then you'll need your script to download and read them on-the-fly using CURL or similar before outputting the content.

Comment: It's not 'vitally important', I just want to make it as hard as possible. The script I linked leaves a link to the .php file in my Chrome download history. The .php script uses facebook info to determine the source, so the link is useless to another person. If they can only determine the source through firewall logs, well that's just okay.

Comment: sounds like you really should just serve a temporary file and remove it after the download completes (or rotate filenames on a daily or hourly basis). even if the content is on a different server you could do it remotely via FTP. You could also dynamically add remove firewall IP entries and add the IPs of users who correctly access the script.

Comment: I don't see any relevance to John's answer. Can you explain what is incorrect? Are you saying you have no control over the remote server? If so you're basically boned unless you keep local copies of the file (and therefore use your own bandwidth).

Comment: I suspect you misunderstand what the PHP script you're refering to does. The script serves the content (therefore the script IS the content). You can only mask this way by serving the content from YOUR server.

Comment: My "incorrect" was referring to "Sorry not possible".  @John's answer allows one to dynamically route the file through the PHP script, hiding the file's actual location.

Comment: @Jonah Indeed, I love how most often the least "correct" answer is accepted. Oh well.

Comment: The only incorrect part of my answer is the first sentence and only because it appeared he was trying to serve the content from the remote server directly. My final answer explains that piping the binary data with the correct headers is the solution and that's when it was accepted.

Answer (score 6):

You mean you want to hide the path of files stored on your server? If this is the case, simply store the files outside of your web root, and serve the files with a PHP script which will make use of readfile() + header() of appropriate headers depending on whether you are serving the file for opening or forced download. See http://php.net/readfile for plenty of examples on forced download scripts.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned, the source files are on a different server, and readfile doesn't accept that.

Comment: Actually yes, it does (assuming you have allow_url_fopen enabled). It does mean it will be temporarily downloaded to your file system, so I guess technically you are still serving it locally.

Comment: allow_url_fopen on which server? the one with the file or the one serving the client? (pardon my ignorance)

Comment: The server serving the client.

Comment: On another note, if you are passing remote url's to readfile, you need to make sure the url begins with http://

Answer (score 0):

If you mean hide the script or the directory the file is coming from, it's a simple answer--you can't.

BUT, you can make it only accessible on your terms, like using a script to render the file (as you have) but only when specific criteria are met. Alternatively you can move the file to a temp/secured directory and allow them direct access, but this also means waiting for the move, providing (what is deemed) reasonable and fair time to download the file, then removing it/deleting it when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cURL to serve as a pass-thru for the content.  This would conceal the source of the actual data, and allow you to secure it any way you choose.  It would also take a lot of bandwidth, roughly 2 times the size of all downloaded files.

Give this a shot and let me know if it works?

```
if ($passesallyoursecurity) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header("Content-Type: application/download"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=filetheyget.ext");

    $ch = curl_init("http://remotedomain.com/dir/file.ext");
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);        
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to end with `exit();` because then you cant render the rest of the page.

Comment: @Moshe, as this is providing a file download, there would be no page to render after.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you use a die() message without any HTML, whatsoever. in the document.

Then, insert the IP Addresses you want the webpage to decline. I would break the IP Addresses you don't like in an array(). Then use an "if" construct to see if any of those IP Addresses are lurking.

```
$decline_ips = array('ip_1' => '127.0.0.1');
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $decline_ips['ip_1']) {
   die("You aren't permitted direct access to this page.\n\n\n\n
   Sources are blank.");
}
```

It works like a charm! And for XTRA-XTRA security, I would recommend inserting the IP address that isn't allowed (when they visit) to the Database so that whenever they try again, both the source is covered and the entire document.

But, you can just use the script I have posted on a different part of the document.